# A JPG image of the 1st image of a GIF using PHP

Tags: php, gif

I want to get the 1st image of the series of images in a gif file using php. I want this so that I can insert a play button to the jpg file and show the gif file when clicked...
Examples are like the videos of dailymotion. In its recommended videos, when you hover the mouse on a jpg file, a gif file plays...and the jpg file is the first image of the gif file.

Comment: OK, so what have you tried? Please post your code here.

Comment: I could not find any way like using the php gd library. Currently, I have to create a jpg myself of the gif...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12551646/how-to-extract-frames-of-an-animated-gif-with-php

Comment: In SO you will get question's answer for your problem not full program of your need

Answer (score 1):

For the first frame in the gif try to open the image in a photo editor. It should open at the first frame. Then save as JPG.

Comment: But that is manually...I want to do it server side as I have to display the GIF image uploaded by the user immediately...like in some video websites, as soon as you upload a video, a jpg is created from the gif...interesting...huh?