# How do I determine how many times a gif loops using PHP

Tags: php, animated-gif

I'd like to know [if there is] a simple way to find out how many times an animated gif loops, using PHP.

As far as I can tell this information is encoded into the header of the gif binary (after a string which is something like "NETSCAPE2.0", for what it's worth), but I've no idea how to read that (in either PHP or any text editor, Sublime gives me what looks like hex codes and TextEdit gives me nonsense).

I'd assume I'd need to read the file look for the above string and *hopefully* the text after it would be an integer defining the number of loops. Maybe?

Any suggestions? I'm happy to play around with any wild ideas!

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not 100% certain, it's been a while since I've used it, but ImageMagick might have something - if your server allows you to install it - it's kinda memory hungry : http://www.imagemagick.org

Comment: In theory, you can animate GIFs for any whole number of loops. But in practice, it's either once or infinite.

Comment: Thanks @CD001, I'd rather avoid memory hungry libs but will give it a bash. Currently assuming gifs loop infinitely as I agree with Blazemonger's assumptions; just would like to *know*, it'll bug me otherwise!

Answer (score 2):

There's some information on the gif format here. It seems to include the information about animation:

http://giflib.sourceforge.net/whatsinagif/bits_and_bytes.html

and this is more specific about what you asked about

http://giflib.sourceforge.net/whatsinagif/animation_and_transparency.html

Comment: Very interesting, I'll digest it and see if I can work something out. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found this class [GifFrameExtractor](https://github.com/Sybio/GifFrameExtractor) From [How to extract frames of an animated GIF with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12551646/how-to-extract-frames-of-an-animated-gif-with-php)

You can get separately an array of images and an array of durations:

```
$frameImages = $gfe->getFrameImages();
$frameDurations = $gfe->getFrameDurations();
```

Combining those two method `$frameImages*$frameDurations` will give you the time for one iteration.

**Compare** it with the time from the beginning of animation to now.

Comment: Thanks! I too am using that library, which works great for extracting the frames and frame durations, however it doesn't tell me how many times the Gif intends to loop (N times or infinite).

Comment: I'm afraid I still don't understand. I don't see how knowing the duration of a single iteration can help me determine how many times it will loop? This isn't in the browser, it's on the command line. I'm batch processing many images, if that clarifies anything?

Answer (score 0):

you can't achieve this without writing some js code...

but you must know/calculate gif's time length for 1 loop.

in your form add

```
<input id='looper' type='hidden' name='loopingTime' value='0'/>
```

add function

```
function loaded(){
    $('#looper').val($('#looper').val()+1);
    //assuming that calculating time with precision 1second is enough to determine number of loops
    setInterval(loaded,1000);
}
```

add call to this method when gif starts animating

```
<img id="photo"
     onload='loaded(this.id)'
     src="a_gif_animation.gif"
     alt="this is some alt text"
     title="this is some title text" />
```

in your action method you'll have a parameter `loopingTime` containig number of seconds played by gif, but youll have to calculate gif loop time somehow.

Comment: This is a JS implementation. I'm after PHP. Thanks anyway.

Comment: i'm confused... where you show your gif using PHP, if it's not in browser ?

Comment: Server cron job which is processing images, not being run in a browser.