# Is there a quick and dirty way to make a thumbnail of the first frame of a gif in php?

Tags: php, thumbnails, gif

The reason I say "quick and dirty" is because truly I don't even need the image re-sized, I just need a non-animated version to be created on upload that will function as a thumbnail until mouse hover which will then load the full gif. I'd like to stay away from Imagick since it looks like a pain to install on wamp. Any easy ways to "break" the gif with php?

Comment: Try: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12554723/661872

Comment: I just had the idea that maybe converting it to another file type like a jpeg may yield the desired results, anyone know if that would work or if it would be worth the trouble. I'm relatively new to php so I'm trying to stay away from classes and more advanced things.