# Extracting certain parts on image with PHP

Tags: php, image, image-processing, imagemagick, gif

I would like to be able to extract radar data from gif which occurs every hour.

This is an example of one gif:
[image]

Data colors can vary according data legend on the right. I would also like that country borders are not visible, as gif is drown in order: base layer, radar data layer, borders layer - I only need pure radar data.

Any suggestion or solution will be very much appriciated!

Comment: Please show how the result will look.

Comment: Sorry, I ve been out of the office. Thanks for your huge help, I've just checked the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the radar data seems to be highly saturated, so you could extract the saturation onto its own layer and threshold it at, say, 85% and use that as the opacity like this:

```
convert radar.gif \
   \( +clone -colorspace hsl -channel S -separate -threshold 85% \) \
     -compose copyopacity -composite result.gif
```

which gives you this, where all the unsaturated colours are now transparent:

[image]

As you can see, it is correctly picking up and retaining all the colours in the "key" on the right, but it also picks up the mauve on the left of the image. Let's make that specific tone transparent:

```
convert radar.gif \
   \( +clone -colorspace hsl -channel S -separate -threshold 85% \) \
      -compose copyopacity -composite                               \
      -fuzz 10% -fill none -opaque "rgb(160,153,255)" result.gif
```

which gives this:

[image]

Now, I presume we need to get rid of the sickly yellow too:

```
convert radar.gif \
  \( +clone -colorspace hsl -channel S -separate -threshold 85% \) \
     -compose copyopacity -composite                               \
     -fuzz 10% -fill none                                          \
     -opaque "rgb(160,153,255)"                                    \
     -opaque "rgb(254,251,175)" result.gif
```

Finally, let's crop to the top left 480x480 px:

```
convert radar.gif -crop 480x480+0+0 +repage \
  \( +clone -colorspace hsl -channel S -separate -threshold 85% \) \
     -compose copyopacity -composite                               \
     -fuzz 10% -fill none                                          \
     -opaque "rgb(160,153,255)"                                    \
     -opaque "rgb(254,251,175)" result.gif
```

[image]

Comment: This is awsome! Tnx! I guess this is ImageMagick, I wanted to make myself things closer and use pure PHP, but I guess I will have to check IM, since I havent figure out anything with PHP. But what I would kindly ask to do here is to remove this border which turned out to be blue here in the end and if it is possible to interpolate colors where borders used to be, now this area is white.

Comment: You can remove the border exactly the same way as I removed the mauve and the yellow. Just get its RGB colour and add another `-opaque "rgb(0,89,129)"` into the list.

Comment: You can use ImageMagick with PHP - just search on StackOverflow for `[imagick]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use '[imagecreatefromgif](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromgif.php)' to retrieve the gif and load it as an GD object (requires GD enabled in the php.ini). From there you can use quite a few image manipulation tricks to cut down to what you want from the gif. The PHP.net site has an example on what you can do with it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you are interested just in the information coded by colours, which us present in some specific frame of the gif, read here about how you can access only one frame if that gif:

[Accessing gif frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12551646/how-to-extract-frames-of-an-animated-gif-with-php)

After that, considering you have a rectangle image, you can scan pixel by pixel, as a matrix, using php function 'imagecolorat'.