# Insert GIF in pdf using rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I am using rmarkdown to generate both HTML and pdf file. In my .Rmd file, I included a GIF like this:

```
![](www/script.gif)
```

When I knit the to HTML it works fine.

```
rmarkdown::render(documentation_file, encoding="UTF-8")
```

However, when I try to knit to PDF using

```
rmarkdown::render(documentation_file, rmarkdown::pdf_document(latex_engine = "xelatex"), encoding="UTF-8")
```

I have the following problem:

```
! LaTeX Error: Unknown graphics extension: .gif.
```

I do not mind to lose the animation of the gif, a static version of it is perfectly fine.

Is there any easy way to include/convert on the fly the GIF to my PDF document?

Comment: Related question in TEX.SE: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7602/how-to-add-a-gif-file-to-my-latex-file

Comment: you can now include animation in pdf, https://resources.rstudio.com/rstudio-conf-2020/one-r-markdown-document-fourteen-demosyihui-xie see 8 min mark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to directly include GIFs in a LaTeX document.

In general LaTeX, you can only include GIFs if you use `latex` to compile your document; when using `pdflatex`, `xelatex` and `lualatex` you need to manually convert your figure to e.g. PNG, JPG or PDF.

RMarkdown by default uses `pdflatex`; while you may change the LaTeX engine by specifying e.g. `latex_engine: xelatex` below `pdf_document` in the YAML header of your document, it is not possible to use `latex` to compile (`latex` would first create a DVI file, which is then converted to a PS and then in turn to a PDF).

So the easiest (and only) solution would be to convert all GIF figures to PNGs (or JPGs), and then include them as images in your RMarkdown document.

Answer (score 2):

Try this in your chunk

```
if (knitr:::is_latex_output()) {
  knitr::asis_output('\\url{....}')
} else {
  knitr::include_graphics("script.gif")
}
```

And in the url put the url to your gif

Answer (score 0):

You could create a snapshot image of the first frame of the gif, https://stackoverflow.com/a/12554723/10346727
I don't think PDF supports gif format, or any moving format for that matter.

Comment: But then I would use the animation in the HTML file.

Comment: You could fix that by only replacing the gif images with image snapshots after converting it to html